# Matching values based on group ID

Tags: r, match

Suppose I have the following data frame ( the actual one represents very large dataset)

```
df<- structure(list(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), y = structure(c(1L, 
6L, NA, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("all", "fall", "hello", 
"hi", "me", "non", "you"), class = "factor"), z = structure(c(5L, 
NA, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("fall", "hi", "me", "mom", 
"non", "you"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like

```
>df
  x     y    z
1 1   all  non
2 1   non <NA>
3 1  <NA>  mom
4 2  fall   hi
5 2    hi fall
6 3 hello  you
7 3   you   me
8 3    me  mom
```

What I am trying to do is to count the number of matched values in each group of `x` (1,2, or 3). For example, the group number `1` has one matched values which is `"non"` (the NA should be ignored). The desired output looks like:

```
  x    n
1 1    1
2 2    2
3 3    2
```

Tried to think in a way of doing this rather than `for-loop` as I have a large dataset but couldn't find my way through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(x) %>%
       summarise(n = sum(y %in% na.omit(z)))
```

Comment: Not really sure why it doesn't give me the desired output. It gives me `n
1 5`

Comment: @AhmedSalhin Works for me. Maybe `plyr` is interfering. I think the packages have some incompatibilities, depending on the order they're loaded in.

Comment: @Frank Yes, you are right. I detached `plyr` and it works for me. Do you know how to overcome the interfering issue?

Comment: @AhmedSalhin load in order `plyr` then `dplyr`, or be explicit about using `summarise` with `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: @LegalizeIt I will specify the package before the function just incase another fuction in `plyr` is interfering with `dplyr`

Comment: @LegalizeIt I mean by specifying the package before the function is `dplyr::summarise`, just like what you mentioned.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin O of course, my bad, I thought you meant putting `library(dplyr)`

Answer (score 4):

Just for nightly fun I've tried a base R solution which of course is ugly as hell.

```
ind <- by(df, df$x, function(x) which(na.omit(x[["y"]]) %in% na.omit(df[["z"]])))
sm <- lapply(ind, length)
cbind(unique(df$x), sm)
sm
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 2
```

Another base R approach, with less code (and with less ugliness I hope):

```
ind <- by(df, df$x, function(x) sum(na.omit(x[["y"]]) %in% na.omit(x[["z"]])))
cbind(unique(df$x), ind)
    ind
1 1   1
2 2   2
3 3   2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`by()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html) and [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html):

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$x,function(g) c(x=g$x[1],n=sum(!is.na(match(g$y,g$z,inc=NA))))));
##   x n
## 1 1 1
## 2 2 2
## 3 3 2
```

Comment: I like this base R solutions... honestly,  mine is longer and clumsy, I prefer this one. A Vote up!